# Как получить названия аргументов из парсера или его группы?

Tags: python, argparse

Можно ли получить названия аргументов, добавленные с помощью `add_argument()` в парсер или его группу, до вызова `parse_args()`?

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--arg')
# тут надо получить строку 'arg' или '--arg' в переменную name
args = parser.parse_args()
print(vars(args)[name])
```

Вариант с ручным добавлением названий в список подразумевает дублицирование кода (т.к. у аргументов разные описания и прочее, просто циклом пройтись нельзя), вариант с `._actions` не задокументирован.

Answer (score 1):

```
def parserArgument():
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument("-i", "--input", type=str, help="...")
    ap.add_argument("-f", "--flag", type=str, help="...")
    return vars(ap.parse_args())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parserArgument()
    if args['input'] is not None:
        name_file = args['input']
    elif args['flag'] is not None:
        flag = args['flag']
```